# How can i create a sliding layout above the preview of Camera?

Tags: android, camera, sliding, drawer

I am making a project using a camera and I wanted to have an extra button that i must be seen in sliding drawer.
I tried it but the screen divides into two, the preview of camera and the place of sliding drawer when open.

My question is how I make may preview of camera serves as background or below the sliding drawer so it will occupy the whole screen?
Thank you. Advices, links and tutorial are so much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the camera preview and the sliding drawer in a relative layout. This way they will overlap and you will get the effect you are looking for.
If you put them in a linear layout for example then the preview will shrink when the drawer is opened.